# Why can I not add these objects to an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I am trying to add the three flying objects to an array list of type flyable which is an abstract interface I have created in my package, this is my code.

```
package labInterface;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class App 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Plane myPlane = new Plane(4, "Boing 747");
        System.out.printf("myPlane: %s%n", myPlane);

        Hangglider myHangglider = new Hangglider(true);
        System.out.printf("myHangglider: %s%n", myHangglider);

        Bird myBird = new Bird("Swallow");
        System.out.printf("myBird: %s%n", myBird);
        
        
        ArrayList<Flyable> flyingThings = new ArrayList<Flyable>();
        flyingThings.add("myPlane");
        flyingThings.add("myHangglider");
        flyingThings.add("myBird");
        
    }

}
```

I get the error "The method add(Flyable) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)".
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

I have tried using `flyingThings.add(new Flyable("myPlane"));` but I get the error, "cannot instantiate the Type Flyable".

Comment: Remove the quotes. `flyingThings.add(myPlane);`

Comment: The objects you add need to be of the `ArrayList`'s type parameter, which is `Flyable`. "myPlane" is of type String. Hence the error.

Comment: Do not change your question after you've already received an answer.

Comment: The answer fixed the problem as asked. But, changing the question so the answer given is no longer applicable is not fair to the person providing the answer. I suggest you consult with your teacher / professor, teacher's aid, or other students taking the course. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not tutorial service. It's not set up so someone can get one problem addressed, and then another, and possibly another, and so on, all for the same code. For something like that, a conversation is needed. But, needing a conversation / tutorial makes the issue inappropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wrote my previous comment because the O/P's response to the answer, plus the attempt to instantiate an interface mentioned in the question shows some misunderstanding of interfaces in Java.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Flyable> flyingThings = new ArrayList<Flyable>();
```

Here you have created an array list which should have datatype of Flyable object.

```
flyingThings.add("myPlane");
flyingThings.add("myHangglider");
flyingThings.add("myBird");
```

Your are trying to add objects of strings i.e "myPlane",.. are strings so that strings could not be added. The solution is to remove those double-quote marks.

```
 flyingThings.add(myPlane);
 flyingThings.add(myHangglider);
 flyingThings.add(myBird);
```

Comment: I removed the quotations and I still have the same error:  The method add(Flyable) in the type ArrayList<Flyable> is not applicable for the arguments (Plane)

Comment: @HalfokayCS When you declare your class is it `class Plane implements Flyable` or something similar? You might need to include the class definition for one or two of `Plane` `Hangglider` and `Bird` for somebody to fix it.